# Can someone please explain the proof that every nonzero integer, n, there is a prime factorization?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm in the process of trying to teach myself number theory and got stuck on trying to understand what is probably a basic, fundamental theorem in number theory. The theorem that *for every nonzero integer, there is a prime factorization*

$$
n = -1^{\epsilon(n)} * \prod_{p} p^{a(p)},
$$

*with the exponents uniquely determined by $n$*.

Can someone please walk through how this function works? I am particularly confused with how $a(p)$ is found and how to determine $\epsilon(n)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: If that's how they put it in the book you're reading, I suggest you get a different book.  That's an unnecessarily complicated way of expressing what on the whole is a fairly simple statement.

Comment: @Dave Washington: What textbook are you using?

Comment: A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory(second edition) by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen

Comment: I wouldn't call that a classical way of introducing the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I think that book (which I don't know, so I'm just guessing) has a very different target from what you need. They probably basically assumes you know that theorem and then just present this form because it's usable for them, but when you don't know it it's unnecessarily complex, so I'm with @David: You should find a different book.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are reading Ireland and Rosen (Graduate Texts in Mathematics) and can't understand the statement in your question, you definitely have the wrong book - this is not an elementary book for beginners.

Comment: Yeah, I'll start searching for a different book tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to $\epsilon(n)$, its only purpose is to determine the sign of $n$. Explicitly
$$
\epsilon(n)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;n>0\\[4pt]
1&\text{if}\;n<0\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
With regard to $a(p)$ . . .

For each prime $p$, the exponent, $a(p)$, is the largest nonnegative integer such that $p^{a(p)}{\,\mid\,}n$.

For example, if $n=-490$, then
$$n = ((-1)^1)\Bigl((2^1)(3^0)(5^1)(7^2)(11^0)(13^0)\cdots\Bigr)$$
Thus, for this example, we have 
\begin{align*}
\epsilon(n)&=1\\[4pt]
a(2)&=1\\[4pt]
a(5)&=1\\[4pt]
a(7)&=2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and $a(p)=0$ for all other primes $p$.

Answer (score 0):

$-1^{\epsilon(n)}$ is only to represent negative numbers, since the product of (positive) primes will always be positive.

$a(p)$ represents the exponent of the prime in the factorization. Generally, given $n$, the only way to find $a(p)$ for each $p$ is to factor. For example, $20 = 2^2 \times 5$, so in this case $a(2)=2$ and $a(5)=5$.

This is an overcomplicated way to present the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). I suggest getting a book that will present it in a more intuitive manner.